# How to replace a string with another string and insert it into the next line of code in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I can't figure out how to replace a string with a string,in my program while it's running.
Is this even possible ?
While the program is running, I want to replace a word with another and then continue running from that line.

How could i do this ?
thanks all

```
hstring.replace("picstart", "up1");
g.drawPixmap(Assets.picstart , 128, 160);
```

Comment: You need to replace a constant with a variable.

Comment: You can't modify your own source code at runtime.  What are you actually trying to do?  You might need to use reflection.

Comment: You can use reflection to lookup a field by name, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your code would look something like this.

```
if (condition) {
    g.drawPixmap(Assets.picstart , 128, 160);
} else {
    g.drawPixmap(Assets.up1 , 128, 160);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable, which means you have to assign the result to a variable:

```
hstring = hstring.replace(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Now, is it possible to know what was the downvote for?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use reflection. Assuming your assets code handles your images, or textures, or whatever the case may be:

```
String hstring = "picstart";
// ... stuff happens
// that forces us to change hstring! ...
hstring = hstring.replace("up1"); // or you could just say hstring = "up1";
g.drawPixmap(Assets.getAssetFor(hstring), 128, 160);
```

Then in your static Asset class you can have:

```
public PixelMap getAssetFor(String identifier) {
     if (identifier.equals("picstart") {
         return new PicStartPixelMap();
     }
     else if (identifier.equals("up1")) {
         return new UpOnePixelMap();
     }
}
```

Comment: im gonna try getassetfor(hstring),maybe thatll do it

Comment: @WilliamMChildsIv You do have to program that function yourself. I'm not talking about any pre-built methods.

Comment: why want hstring work like this?>>>> g.drawPixmap(Assets.hstring , 128, 160);

Comment: You have to offer a bit more information? Is Assets.hstring a String? Is drawPixMap a function? Is hstring set or is it null? Does hstring have the correct String value?

Comment: in the assets class >>public static Pixmap<<is picstart;in the loadscreen class>>Assets.picstart = g.newPixmap("picstart.png", PixmapFormat.ARGB4444);in the class im in i call >>g.drawPixmap(Assets.hstring , 128, 160); but hstring is a string but nut in the assets class

Comment: What does your error message tell you? You can always start a new question on StackOverflow for faster help.